# How to iterate over ids in mongodb and perform functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have `entity` which has response like this

```
[
    {
        "public": false,
        "_id": "5eb6da3635b1e83",
        "createdAt": "2020-05-09T16:28:38.493Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-05-09T16:28:38.493Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "public": false,
        "_id": "5ed54f345c1672",
        "createdAt": "2020-06-01T18:56:48.459Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-06-01T18:56:48.459Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

There is another model called `Review` which is linked to `entity` through the `_id`. ( the `Review` model has a field called `entityId`)

the `Review` model has a field called `rating` which I want to return so essentially what I want to do is go through each `id`  of `entity` response find the corresponding review having same `entityId` as `id` and return `rating` of that `review`.

I having trouble iterating over all the `id` of `entity` response. Looking for an efficient to do it without using for loop.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do a [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), which is like a join in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to iterate over all the entities you can't do it more efficiently than using a for loop, or using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) if you prefer that syntax.